# Serve React with Django Server

Tags: django, reactjs

I am following [this tutorial](https://alphacoder.xyz/dead-simple-react-django-setup/) in order to serve **React** through **Django** server, but I only get a blank page when I access `http://localhost:8000/admin`, and I get the following errors on Django local server console:

```
[20/Jun/2020 17:05:08] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 2217
[20/Jun/2020 17:05:08] "GET /static/css/main.5f361e03.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1821
[20/Jun/2020 17:05:08] "GET /static/js/main.853c8ab9.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1815
[20/Jun/2020 17:05:08] "GET /static/js/2.6d20342a.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1806
[20/Jun/2020 17:05:08] "GET /static/js/2.6d20342a.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1806
[20/Jun/2020 17:05:08] "GET /static/js/main.853c8ab9.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1815
```

I made all, and only, the changes stated in the tutorial.

**EDIT**

I have managed to make `http://localhost:8000/admin` work. I just had to add a coma in `TEMPLATES`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build'),
        ],
        # ...
    }
]
```

But I still get the same error with `http://localhost:8000/`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, have tried just accessing the root path, `http://localhost:8000` without the `/admin`? Those `build` files are often served at the root path. In fact, your `index.html` is being served at that root path too. Can you try that and let us know?

Comment: @MwamiTovi Nothing, just the same

Comment: Just serve them separately. Such an approach to serve a React SPA from Django never worked for me. It's far easier to serve them separately.